# Summarize values based on two columns DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I'm new to DAX and don't get how it works (I'm studying its context transitions and so on). What I would like to do is to calculate the marked column without duplicating the stock. I mean, it should only sum stock once by PRODUCT. In this case, instead of 480, it should be 240 in every line (including the one that is 0, not sharing product).

[image]

This is my measure:

```
  REF STOCK*LINEA :=
  CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Production[REF_STOCK] );
    FILTER (
        ALLEXCEPT (Production; Production[SIAC] );
        Production[PENDING_UNITS] > 0
            && Production[SIAC 1] <> "SIAC"
    )
  )
```

EDIT: I think I made it.

This measure apparently works, but I'm not sure if it is correct for what I want to achieve. Will it work with every case?

```
REF STOCK*LINEA :=
CALCULATE (
    SUMX (
        SUMMARIZE ( Production; Production[SIAC]; Production[REF]; Production[Description] );
        [Avg of REF_STOCK]
    );
    FILTER (
        ALLEXCEPT ( Production; Production[SIAC] );
        Production[PENDING_UNITS] > 0
            && Production[SIAC 1] <> "SIAC"
    )
)
```

Please confirm it should work as expected. Thank you!